# My package in OpenWRT does not compile

Tags: openwrt

I have downloaded OpenWRT source from git and build it. I created a simple helloworld package with the required Makefile in package/helloworld directory and build it. But it does not seem to be doing anything. Following is the log:

```
sonal@sonal-ThinkPad:~/openwrt$ make V=99 package/helloworld/compile
WARNING: your configuration is out of sync. Please run make menuconfig, oldconfig or defconfig!
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/sonal/openwrt'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/sonal/openwrt/package/libs/toolchain'
if [ -f /home/sonal/openwrt/staging_dir/target-mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/pkginfo/toolchain.default.install.clean ]; then rm -f /home/sonal/openwrt/staging_dir/target-mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/pkginfo/toolchain.default.install /home/sonal/openwrt/staging_dir/target-mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/pkginfo/toolchain.default.install.clean; fi; echo "libc" >> /home/sonal/openwrt/staging_dir/target-mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/pkginfo/toolchain.default.install
if [ -f /home/sonal/openwrt/staging_dir/target-mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/pkginfo/toolchain.default.install.clean ]; then rm -f /home/sonal/openwrt/staging_dir/target-mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/pkginfo/toolchain.default.install /home/sonal/openwrt/staging_dir/target-mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/pkginfo/toolchain.default.install.clean; fi; echo "libgcc" >> /home/sonal/openwrt/staging_dir/target-mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/pkginfo/toolchain.default.install
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sonal/openwrt/package/libs/toolchain'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/sonal/openwrt/package/helloworld'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sonal/openwrt/package/helloworld'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sonal/openwrt'`enter code here`


Thanks
Sonal
```

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.prplfoundation.org/wiki/Creating_an_OpenWrt_package_for_a_web_page

This above link will guide you how to build own package. I had also made own luci pages with above link. It will guide you from scratch.

If you want to create only hello world page then no need to create package, you just make new directory name as **files** in **'/home/sonal/openwrt/'**
and then go to files directory and make new directory as **www** in **'/home/sonal/openwrt/files/'**. No custom packages requires for it.

Comment: If you find this answer useful, then tick it as right. So, anyone can refer this . Thank You.